# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_slash'

Tags: python, pip, discord.py

I'm trying to install a module called ["discord_slash"](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command) and when I use it in a python file it displays the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_slash'".
I've tried uninstalling it and installing it again but it's not working.
[image: This is an example of what happens exactly]

Comment: The quickstart guide shows the module name is `interactions` not `discord_slash` https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html and so does their setup.py https://github.com/interactions-py/library/blob/stable/setup.py

Comment: Thank you for your comment @DavinderJolly, but in this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygc-HdZHO5A) they're just using the discord_slash module and not interactions.

Comment: ah right it seems older versions of the modules seemed to be named `discord_slash` so if you want that you wanna install an old version of the module so
`pip uninstall discord-py-slash-command` and then `pip install discord-py-slash-command==1.1.2` <- this will install the same version being used in the video for you

Comment: also i would recommend looking into new versions of discord.py which also come with slash_commands built in (idk if that's released yet so you might have to get the dev version for that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're attempting to use the legacy v3 version import of the library, available [here](https://github.com/interactions-py/library/tree/legacy-v3). As of 4.0, you should be using `import interactions`.

Based on a comment, I understand you're watching a video from 2021, if you'd like to use a similar version you can use [discord-py-slash-command 3.0.3](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/3.0.3/) which is the latest release of that branch.

You can install that like this:
`pip install discord-py-interactions=3.0.3`

I'd highly recommend you go ahead and find a newer video guide or read their [Quickstart documentation here](https://discord-interactions.rtfd.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) so you can have the up to date library and features.