# Python not recognizing an installed library?

Tags: python, pip

Im trying to run a script on a AWS EC2 Windows 2019 instance but its not running even tho the library is installed. The lib in question is "discord-py-slash-command" but other libs like requests install and run normally (they are imported earlier in the file)

I tried `pip install discord-py-slash-command` I tried `python -m pip install discord-py-slash-command` all successfully install the library but the script doesnt recognize it. I also reinstalled Python with all extra add-ons and I still have no idea what to do next

Comment: Try [discord-py-interactions](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-interactions/) instead. I'm not sure what the difference is, but they link to the same github and documentation, which says to install using `pip install -U discord-py-interactions`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72547362/7976758

Comment: The issue isnt in the library being wrong I have it installed on my home PC and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Interpreter again. Your project interpreter may be not the python version that you Installed.

In Pycharm, you can simply check it by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`S` > `Project` > `Python Interpreter`