# There is No Module named discord_slash

Tags: python

No matter what I try my code simply does not work because it is important not to waste time I will only include the relevant code to this situation:

```
import discord_slash.utils.manage_commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
```

And the output I get is this:

```
import discord_slash.utils.manage_commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
```

Sidenote:I am using Replit not that I think it'll change the outcome or anything
but in case it has an impact my repl.it link will be attached -->[Click Here to see Replit](https://replit.com/@IvanIvanovna/GuiltyThoroughKilobyte)

Comment: So the output you get is the code you try to execute? Do you use `cat` to execute the code?

Comment: this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547116/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-discord-slash) has your answer. You should be using `import interactions`, discord_slash is from older versions.